# spark showing NULL value while parsing JSON file

Tags: json, apache-spark

I have a JSON file that I am reading in spark.

The schema is getting displayed however when I am trying to read the info column or any sub-element it is always NULL. (which is not NULL)

```scala
//reading file
val df = spark.read.json("FilePath")

df.printSchema()

    root
     |-- data_is: boolean (nullable = true)
     |-- Student: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- JoinDate: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- LeaveDate: string (nullable = true)
     |-- Info: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- details: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |-- Father_salary: double (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- Mother_salary: double (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- Address: String (nullable = true)
     |    |-- studentInfo: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- Age: double (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- Name: String (nullable = true)

df.select("Student").show()
```

shows the filed value in Student element
even when I parse `Student.Id` I can get the ID

But whenever parsing the Info, I am always getting a NULL value which is not NULL in the file.

```
df.select("Info").show() // is showing as NULL
df.select("Info.detail").show() // is showing as NULL
```

even `Info.Summary` is NULL.

Can anybody suggest how to get the actual field value instead of NULL?

JSON File

```json
{"Student":{"JoinDate":"20200909","LeaveDate":"20200909","id":"XA12"},"Info":{"studentInfo":{"Age":13,"Name":"Alex"},"details":[{"Father_salary":1234.00,"Mother_salary":0,"Address":""}]},"data_is":true}
```

Comment: post your sample

Comment: @Lamanus, i Added the example json file

Comment: I have tried reading your date the way you showed and then running the select and everything is fine. So it there anything else you are not showing us? Is there any step in between?

Comment: In addition to the above comment there also seems to be a typo when selecting "Info.detail" as in the JSON string the key name is actually "Info.detail**s**".